# Converter decimal para ushort

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo

Preciso converter um valor `decimal` para `ushort` na minha aplicação:

Existe essa possibilidade?

Se sim, como converter?

Tentei usar o `Convert.ToInt16(value)`, mas não funcionou.

Exemplo em console:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   decimal value= 15;
   //Nao é possivel converter, pergunta se existe uma conversao explicita...
   ushort newValue = Convert.ToInt16(value);

   Console.WriteLine(newValue);
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Existe uma função específica para conversão em ushort que é o **[Convert.ToUInt16()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.touint16(v=vs.110).aspx)**. Tente assim:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   decimal value= 15;
   //Nao é possivel converter, pergunta se existe uma conversao explicita...
   ushort newValue = Convert.ToUInt16(value);

   Console.WriteLine(newValue);
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Essencialmente não deveria fazer isto, por duas razões:

- Provavelmente está perdendo dados já que um decimal não é um inteiro positivo. Ele pode até ser, mas não há garantias. Claro, pode verificar antes e só depois de ter certeza que a conversão será bem sucedida fazer, mas não parece estar se certificando disto. O negativo até geraria erro.
- O uso dos tipos não sinalizados devem ficar restritos ao baixo nível, para comunicar com o sistema operacional ou outra linguagem que exija que o dado seja assim. Há uma série de implicações no seu uso que não é fácil acertar. Só o use quando tem completo domínio da computação.

Provavelmente tem uma solução melhor para o problema. Mas se ainda quer insistir nisso precisa responder uma pergunta:

Que comportamento espera ter a conversão de um dado com parte decimal? Deve truncar ou arredondar?

Se precisa arredondar com critério próprio tem que fazer na mão antes.

Você pode mandar converter com o método correto, do jeito que estava fazendo, ou pode usar um simples *cast* que neste caso funciona bem, desde que deseje o truncamento ou saiba que jamais poderá ter um valor com parte decimal.

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Convert;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var x = 15.7M;
        WriteLine(ToUInt16(x));
        WriteLine((ushort)x);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DjVJu8). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l7zPUv). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/DecimalToUshort.cs).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar `(ushort)`:

```
decimal value= 15;
ushort newValue = (ushort)value;
```